# Show that the lines joining the origin to the point of intersection of the line

Tags: analytic-geometry

Show that the lines joining the origin to the point of intersection of the line $x+y=1$ with the curve $4x^2+4y^2+4x-2y-5=0$ are at right angles to each other.

How do I approach this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

By the process of homogenisation the pair of lines have the equation

$4(x^2+y^2)+(4x-2y)(x+y)-5(x+y)^2=0$ which simplifies to $3x^2-8xy-3y^2=0$

We know that for the pair of lines $ax^2+2hxy+by^2=0, a+b = 0 \Rightarrow$ they are orthogonal.

Here the same holds, and hence the pair of lines are perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The equation of any quadratic curve passing through the intersection will be $$4x^2+4y^2-2y+4x+5+k(x+y-1)^2=0$$

Now this has to pass through the origin $\implies5+k=0$

Now rearrange to form a quadratic equation in $x$ or in $y$

and solve.

Answer (score 0):

Solving of the system gives 
$$4x^2+4(1-x)^2+4x-2(1-x)-5=0$$ or
$$8x^2-2x-3=0,$$ which gives the following points: $\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4}\right)$ and $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)$.

Now, $$m_1=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{1}{3}$$ and
$$m_2=\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{-\frac{1}{2}}=-3$$ and since $m_1m_2=-1$, we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Replace $x$ with $1-y$ in the equation of the circle to find the two abcissa of the intersection.

Now we know how to find the gradient of a straight line joining two points